# TF400789 - The host cannot be started. The host is in the process of being serviced

Tags: tfs

I have encountered this problem after trying to create a new project. The task has timed out and my efforts to re-run the job were blocked by the following error:
[image: TFS2018-You cannot re-run the selected servicing job]

Then I tried to stop the collection and restart it. This time the collection failed to start with the error I have mentioned in the title.

I tried to requeue the CreateProject job using the instructions in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a7f98cf-13c2-43b0-8092-cd669daec103/tf400789-the-host-testcollection-cannot-be-started-the-host-is-in-the-process-of-being?forum=tfsadmin) link. The SQL instructions worked fine (with a few modifications), but the queued job still does not run.

I have verified the tfs job agent and it is running
[image]

I have also tried restarting the server (just in case)
Any suggestions?

Comment: btw, I'm using TFS2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little Root Cause Analysis revealed that the thing blocking my project collection from going online was a queued job that seemed never to run.
So I figured if that record is deleted from tables tracking it, I will be able to get the collection online (It is always a good idea to have an updated backup, just in case).

So, I did the following:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM   vw_ServicingJobDetail
ORDER BY QueueTime DESC
```

to get the jobId for the problematic job.

then I tried deleting this record from the concerned tables:

```
DELETE FROM [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_JobQueue] 
  where jobid = 'jobId';

   DELETE FROM vw_ServicingJobDetail
  where jobid = 'jobId';
```

and it worked like a charm ;)